# "For the lack of” or “for lack of"?

Tags: definite-article

> The trials that followed the murders of Falcone and Borsellino convicted the people who planted the bombs and planned the assassinations, but a wider investigation into powers behind the attacks had to be closed **for lack of evidence**.

Source: [Newsweek](https://www.newsweek.com/italy-mafia-mob-sicily-murder-prosecutor-giovanni-falcone-613971)

Should there be the definite article before the word "lack"?

Comment: My personal choice would be to replace *for* and use an *indefinite* article in that specific sentence: *had to be closed* ***due to a*** *lack of evidence.*

Comment: *Newsweek* articles are in general trustworthy with regard to the use of language.

Comment: This is the kind of question that Google Books is very good for.  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for+lack+of+evidence%22&num=20&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_u5ru2YHeAhUlnuAKHVEZCZcQ_AUIFCgB&biw=1592&bih=940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[for lack of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20lack%20of)*** is an idiomatic expression and there is no article:

> not having (the thing specified)
>
> - They called it a comet, for lack of a better term/word.
> - For lack of anything better to do, we went to the park.

(M-W)

But a check with [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20lack%20of%2C%20for%20the%20lack%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20lack%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20lack%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows that both versions are used  “***for the lack of***” and “***for lack of***”.

Comment: The similar expression is "for want of", which too, is sometimes [used with THE article](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+lack+of%2Cfor+the+lack+of%2Cfor+want+of%2Cfor+the+want+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20lack%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20lack%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20want%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20want%20of%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: And **absence of** as in **absence of malice**.

Comment: @Rompey: *the absence of malice*?